# call method with parameter of type class and check class type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have the following classes:

```
class Permission {
  name: string;
}

class EditBasketPermission extends Permission {
  basketId: number;
}

class EditProductPermission extends Permission {
  basketId: number;
  projectId: number;
}
```

Then I have a method that authorizes, or not, the permission:

```
authorize(permission: Permission) : boolean {

  // 1 - Check the permission type
  // 2 - Authorize the request based on the permission data

}
```

How to check the permission type so I can decide how to evaluate it?

And in my HTML I have the following:

```
<button *ngIf="authorize(???)">Edit</button>
```

How to pass an EditProductPermission when calling the method authorised?

The problem is that permission type has different types of inputs.

Comment: Are you asking how to check what the derived type of `permission`, the argument to `authorize` is? Or are you asking how to pass the correct `Permission`-derived type to `authorize` in the HTML? We can answer the former question, but the latter we can only guess at because we have a single line of HTML code to go on. How do permissions flow in your application?

Comment: You check the type of an object using `obj instanceof MyClass` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about this.

1. You can use JavaScript's [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to detect the type of object you're given.
2. You can add a `permissionType` property (maybe a string or an enum?) and expect each extending class to return some corresponding value for you to switch on.
3. If the shape of each permission type is enough to tell you which kind it is, you could check for things like the presence of a `basketId` and `projectId` to deduce which type you're looking at.

Typescript has [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) which can be based on instanceof or your own custom logic, allowing you to have variables be strongly typed once you've determined that they're of a given type.

Finally, depending on your architecture, it may be worth considering taking an object-oriented approach by associating the authorize logic with the Permission class itself, so instead of calling `authorize(permission)` you would call `permission.authorize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach?

```
authorize(permission: Permission) : boolean {

  // 1 - Check the permission type
  // 2 - Authorize the request based on the permission data

  const props = []
  for (const key in permission) {
    if (permission.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      props.push[key]
  }
  // props is now an array of the specialised permission object keys

}
```